# Chromecast - Sending text message to YouTube receiver

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast

I implemented a chromecast application, it will join to the YouTube session which is already established by the user from YouTube cast feature. Used "Cast.CastApi.joinApplication(mApiClient).setResultCallback(connectionResultCallback)" to do this.

I think that when we cast movie from YouTube app, it will launch his own receiver app in chromecast for content play.

Now I'm trying to send some text messages from my sender app to receiver app (which is YouTube receiver in our case).

According to the google-cast-sdk, I implemented "MessageReceivedCallback" and getting success acknowledgement when I send text messages but the message is not getting displayed in receiver.

Could you please give me a clue to send the text messages to YouTube receiver app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sending a message is not something that the sender can decide to do on its own; it is a collaborative and coordinated process between a sender and the receiver. In this case, YouTube receiver is not designed to listen for your messages so they will not go anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. If displaying msg in YouTube receiver is not possible, I rather trying to code own receiver for this. Could you please suggest me the type of receiver (styled or custom) which will suite for the below requirements?

Comment: Receiver should work like below: 1) Receiver app should play the YouTube Video content upon casting any movie from sender app (I have movie ID's with me). 2) Do I need to implement any authentication process in-order to play YouTube video content in custom receiver. 3) If point(1 & 2) are possible, receiver app should listen the events like play, pause, skip, mute/UN-mute and should display text messages which are sent from sender app.

Comment: Actually I'm exploring Receiver app development API for doing above things, and your suggestions would be helpful for me in-order to take quick decision. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My suggestion on what exactly?

Comment: Is it possible to play YouTube movie content in receiver app for which sender app will send movie ID?

Comment: Some folks have had some level of success with embedded iframe approach but that has serious drawbacks (such as no way to dismiss ads, etc) so there is no perfect way to do that currently.

Comment: Ok, I used iframe to play YouTube video. But here I have a problem with the premium content. Will you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944779/chromecast-custom-receiver-with-youtube-iframe-api-displaying-the-uploader-ha