# Chromecast Custom Receiver with YouTube Iframe API - Displaying "The uploader has not made this video available in your country" message

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, chromecast

I'm working on ChromeCast custom receiver app and using the YouTube iFrame API for loading YT videos. The issue is that receiver app displaying "The uploader has not made this video available in your country" message when I cast the YouTube Premium content.

I think we need to provide some authentication process to access YT premium content, How can I add authentication process in receiver app to play YT premium content?

Thanks in advance...